# Can't generate vertical space between tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I realize this is probably a really simple issue but I'm a complete beginner.

I am auto-generating code very similar to the LaTeX code below. However no matter what I do I can't get space between the two tables - vspace just doesn't seem to work.

However, if I have a figure after these tables vspace then works fine between the tables and the figure.

Does anyone have any advice please? I added

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

today as I don't want paragraph formatting.

THANKS a lot for any help,

Tom.

```
%% WriteReport.m method created this file.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry    {verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={MyOutput},
pdfauthor={Autogenerated by MyOutput}}
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\usepackage{color}
\lhead{MyOutput}
\begin{document}
\section{\textsf{Section title}}
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
   \hline
   one & two \\
   \hline
   one & two \\
   \hline
   one & two \\
   \hline
   one & two \\
   \hline
   one & two \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\newline
\vspace*{1 cm}
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
   \hline
   three & four \\
   \hline
   three & four \\
   \hline
   three & four \\
   \hline
   three & four \\
   \hline
   three & four \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a `\newline` *after* the `\vspace` as well.

So

```
\newline
\vspace*{1 cm}
\newline
```

instead.

Comment: Duh, told you I was a beginner :)

Just out of interest, why do I need the new line afterwards? I know what I was doing was wrong but wouldn't the vspace just insert the space and then the new table would start from there?

Comment: @Tom: from what I understand the `\vspace` inserts a `0` width vertical space. Without the newline after the `\vspace` the tabular is set next to the `0` width `vspace`. If you put a `\newline` *after* the last tabular and then place something there, you should see the vspace there. You shouldn't really need the `\newline` before the `\vspace`, you can just move ti after and it should be fine. The `\vspace` is then set next to the first tabular then you get a newline and TeX will respect the verical space and place the next line that amount lower.

Comment: I'd leave an empty line before `\vspace`, rather than `\newline`; a `\newline` after `\vspace` is definitely wrong.

Comment: @egreg: A `\par` token before would do as well indeed. why is a `\newline` after wrong exactly?

Comment: @wh1t3 `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected`? So it's wrong (and useless if you put `\par` or an empty line, which is exactly the same).

Comment: @egreg: I don't get that warning.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to put the "\vspace*{1 cm}" inside the following table, i.e. after the
"\begin{table}", just before the "\caption{my table's caption}".