# How to increase the vertical space between two "touching" tables?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, threeparttable, tabulary

I skimmed [Can't generate vertical space between tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38893/cant-generate-vertical-space-between-tables) but am looking for sth slightly different: I don't really want to keep the tables together *necessarily* - I'm happy to let LaTeX (or whoever for that matter :) decide. But iff they are to appear together, then I'd want some extra space. As I'm using `threeparttable`, a make-shift solution could be to just use a "blind" footnote, but I'd imagine someone can come up with sth far more elegant than that...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{this is my first table's captive caption}
% \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{8}{L}}
% \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}} \toprule
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}} \toprule
× & TOTALLY & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & {4000} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
DDD 1 & 47.6 & 29.1 & 1.0 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 15.2 & 0.0\\
Unweighted average: & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
DDD & 39.4545 & 9.8695 & 15.3365 & 0.6915 & 2.246 & 10.6705 & 0.5105\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note ...
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{this is my first table's captive caption}
% \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{8}{L}}
% \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}} \toprule
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}} \toprule
× & TOTALLY & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & {4000} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
DDD 1 & 47.6 & 29.1 & 1.0 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 15.2 & 0.0\\
Unweighted average: & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
BBB & 33.8 & 11.3 & 9.1 & 0.4 & 1.8 & 11.0 & 0.2\\
GGG & 32.9904 & 8.60325 & 9.3845 & 0.0495 & 1.43225 & 10.79525 & 0.119\\
DDD & 39.4545 & 9.8695 & 15.3365 & 0.6915 & 2.246 & 10.6705 & 0.5105\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note ...
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The idea is to keep both tables together but just increase their vertical separation? If this is so, use only one `table` environment and add `\vspace{<length>}` between the two `threeparttable`s.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes and no; I had skimmed http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38893/cant-generate-vertical-space-between-tables; I don't really want to keep the tables together *necessarily* - I'm happy to let LaTeX (or whoever for that matter :) decide. But iff they are to appear together, *then* I'd want some extra space. As I'm using `threeparttable`, a make-shift solution could be to just use a "blind" footnote, but I'd imagine someone can come up with sth *far more* elegant than that...

Comment: Perhaps you could add that explanation to your question, so your intent would be clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floats appearing in the same page at the top or at the bottom are separated by `\floatsep` space.

The default for the `article` class is `12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`

Just say, in your document preamble,

```
\setlength{\floatsep}{24pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}
```

(or the value you find most suitable).

Comment: ... as has been mentioned here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-figures-tables-and-text and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25828/how-to-remove-change-the-vertical-spacing-before-and-after-an-algorithm-environ before :)